# need to sort picklist values

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a picklist with values as reports name...When I used below query it is not sorting on visualforce page . From order by docs sorting of picklist is a special case "picklist sorting is defined by the picklist sort determined during setup."

here is my class :

```
public with sharing class PicklistExmCtrl {

  public string selectedReport{get;set;} 

  public PicklistExmCtrl(){
  }

   public List<SelectOption> getReports() {
            List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
            for(Report repoRec:[Select id,Name from Report order by Name ASC]){
              options.add(new SelectOption(repoRec.id,repoRec.Name));
            }

            return options;
    }  

}
```

and vf page :

```
<apex:page controller="PicklistExmCtrl">
<apex:form > 
 <apex:outputPanel > 
    <apex:pageBlock title="Picklist Example" >
        <apex:pageBlockSection title=" " columns="1">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Select Name:"/>
                <apex:selectList id="selList" value="{!selectedReport}" size="1">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Reports}"/>
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:outputPanel> 

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

thnx in advanced!!

The above code is working for me there is a issue with the permissions.. Thanx To all ..

I just mail to client to give me permession for accessing report names and he added me to that group and my problem got solved :)
Thanx to all!! You all are grt !!!

Comment: Have you tried to use `options.sort()`?

Comment: Thanx mast0r for reply ...and the above code is working for me there is a issue with the permissions..
Thanx To all ..